# Edit clearly violating my answer voted `approve` by reviewer

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

[image]

I have recently posted to the topic with a bounty opened. It's tagged [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) and my answer contains some pseudo-code.

The question got edited by a quite new user (rep. 190) by wrapping my pseudo-code into a snippet. I have obviously rejected the edit but I was surprised by the review summary, where someone has voted to approve this edit.

Is it me inappropriately understanding the purpose of `Suggested edits` or the one who has accepted the edit request which clearly violates my answer?

The review can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13694562).

What would be moderators' reaction if I flag my answer to moderator attention? Would this flag be rejected or not? I would add appropriate comment. However, I believe this is not what the moderator-attention flag is for.

Comment: A good thing to do in that case is to stal... inspect a reviewer's profile to see other occurrences of unacceptable approvals, then flag for moderator attention with links to all problematic reviews. If you can't see other problematic reviews, blame the reviewer's cat or something.

Comment: Welcome to edit reviews... where the improvements are made up and the OP's intentions don't matter... :-(

Comment: I don't get the drama, the edit *was* rejected.  That you did it yourself instead of letting another 4 people review the edit just doesn't matter.  The odds that this edit would ever have been approved are minuscule.  Even if it did then simply click [rollback].  Drama averted.

Comment: @HansPassant the drama is that if I was offline, it might be approved. And another thing is that I'm already banned from reviewing for marking requires editing instead of unclear of you're asking which is not destructive at all when dis case is.

Comment: Kinda random isn't it?  The system worked, the edit *was* reverted and a reviewer *was* caught not paying attention by an audit.  Come back when it failed, propose a solution.

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334675/code-snippets-are-a-pest

Comment: @xenteros Even if you were offline and it was approved, you would have been notified once you came online. Wouldn't have been the end of the world.

Comment: @xenteros if you think reviews are taken seriously, you must take a look at this one (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/94469)

Comment: Awww, that's adorable. Some people actually believe pseudo-code is HTML. (I mean, it *is* a valid HTML fragment, but that's like saying whitespace is valid in any language, including Whitespace.)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That was a bad edit and a bad review. Stack Snippets are for things that can be executed in the browser, which pseudo-code by definition is not.

You could flag the review for moderator attention. Whether or not that flag will be deemed helpful is an open question.
Reviewers don't usually get suspended over a single bad review, unless they approved spam or vandalism.

If you want to flag, look for other bad edits and bad reviews that these users have made recently. I generally look for 3 bad edits / 3 bad reviews in the last 2 days. And the edit on your own post counts.
Then, flag one of the posts with a custom mod flag, and explain the situation. 3 recent bad edits should give a moderator sufficient ground to hand out an edit suspension. Likewise, 3 bad reviews should give the moderator sufficient ground to justify a review suspension.

You will have to have some patience. Custom mod flags can linger for a long time, unfortunately. But eventually they will be handled.

Comment: Both the reviewer and editor have been handled, because there was more than this one edit involved. A one-time bad review (aside from approving obvious things like spam and trolling) can be explained away, but patterns of bad reviews or edits are where we'll intervene.

Comment: @BradLarson I'm glad to hear that it was handled, thank you! Hopefully they'll learn and improve. I've noted that bad edit suggesters tend to become bad reviewers. The earlier we can show them how to edit properly, the better.

Comment: In general, why wouldn't it be good to flag a bad review?  If the OP knows what's what, and knows that the edit is incorrect, the community should reward such oversight not penalize it.  If the review is performed by someone who doesn't have enough knowledge on the subject to see that the edit is bad, that's the definition of a bad approval to me and it should be flagged.

Comment: @BenPen A flag over a single bad edit or review when the user otherwise has a good record is a waste of moderator time. What would they do besides fix the post? Just fix the issue yourself in that case. Do *a little* legwork to make sure the mod doesn't have to waste their time only to find out they won't take any action.

Comment: @jpmc26 Gotcha, so bad edit/review policing does fall to the author to some extent, then...

Comment: @BenPen The author is more likely to notice bad edits, but I'd use the broader term "community." A reviewer who ran across this review could do the same, or even just someone who came across the answer trying to solve their own problem. Anyway, yes, community moderation is a staple of SE. ;)

Comment: Yes, true, I'll keep working on clarity and tone...