# Code snippets are a pest

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I find it extremely cumbersome that code snippets add lots of buttons and borders and make it much harder to read through questions.

I answer a lot of question in [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2), and in a lot of questions snippets are used to format the source while about 1 of 500 snippets is actually runnable code and then it's usually just plain html without any code.

When code snippets are used for code that is not actually runnable, they add a lot of clutter that doesn't add any value.
At first glance the page consists mostly of buttons and borders and I have to refocus to actually be able to see the relevant parts of the question.

- make it more obvious that snippets should only be used for runnable code or prevent reuse in some other way
- add another button that allows to remove snippets with one click when they are inappropriate.

A few examples from the last 3h

- [Angular 2 Component is not part of any NgModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527722/angular-2-component-is-not-part-of-any-ngmodule)
- [Expression has changed after it was checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529461/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)
- [Angular2 Routers are not detecting Dynamic Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526406/angular2-routers-are-not-detecting-dynamic-content)

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534984/angular2-service-method-http-post-and-subscribing-to-promise-for-authenticating

**update**

Found also

- [Stack Snippets being misused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused)
- [Abusing the Code Snippet for wrong languages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283108/abusing-the-code-snippet-for-wrong-languages?rq=1)
- [Convert code snippet to code block button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291472/convert-code-snippet-to-code-block-button?rq=1)
- [Replace code snippets by normal code block if JavaScript tag is absent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276409/replace-code-snippets-by-normal-code-block-if-javascript-tag-is-absent?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Should it be more obvious that stack snippets are only meant for HTML/CSS/JS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277602/should-it-be-more-obvious-that-stack-snippets-are-only-meant-for-html-css-js?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Replace code snippets by normal code block if JavaScript tag is absent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276409/replace-code-snippets-by-normal-code-block-if-javascript-tag-is-absent?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How can we keep people from using 'JavaScript/ HTML/ CSS snippet' option with other languages?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375023/how-can-we-keep-people-from-using-javascript-html-css-snippet-option-with-ot)

Comment: While we are at it can remove them from languages they do not belong on, or at least hide them?  I hate having to edit out code snippets in C++.

Comment: Angular2 uses TypeScript and it's possible to make it run in sippets but usually people don't bother to set it up properly. I also hate it.

Comment: Related or even duplicate : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274636/code-snippet-as-a-formatting-tool?rq=1

Comment: Snippets as whole were a poor, half-baked feature. Their design fails to address the use cases that JSFiddle was great for; meanwhile, their abuse by those who don't understand the editor's UI has lumbered us with a bunch of broken posts and extra cleanup work. They have done harm on net, and the site would be better without them.

Comment: I guess they are nice on tags that are about pure JS and jQuery but besides that, I also doubt they provide much value.

Comment: Sometimes I post a comment like "I can't run that JavaScript" when the code is actually Java but with wrong snippet language. And funnily/annoyingly, a user once rejected my edit when I removed that wrong snippet language.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer even there they suck for 99% of questions. Typically with UI code (which is all that snippets can reasonably be used for) there is a small amount of code (perhaps a single line) that actually answers the question, but a dozen or dozens of lines needed (including HTML, JS, and CSS) to set up a demo that the answer works. The ideal solution is thus to put the *answer* in the, well, *answer*, and to then stick a demo behind a link, where it can be opened and studied in full on its own page. JSFiddle lets me do this; Stack Snippets demand I either hide the demo code or inline it.

Comment: @MarkAmery: I find that that is a awfully pessimistic view of the functionality of stack snippets. There are [plenty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643617/create-table-using-javascript/14644462#14644462) [of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121719/html5-canvas-background-image-repeat/14121902#14121902) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35138529/1835379) where a function can easily be demo'd using a snippet.

Comment: @Cerbrus whoa, stack snippets have a console now?! Didn't know that - I see it was announced on MSE instead of MSO, so not surprised I never saw it. Wow, that actually adds some utility.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Aye, it's a pretty neat (overdue) feature. :D

Comment: JSFiddle just hides the code in another site. I hate it when I see someone answer with "Try this: [fiddle]" and yes, I flag those as link-only, but using JSFiddle for SO questions/answers encourages that kind of laziness. I've also had many people argue with me when I ask them to include code in the question itself ("It's right there, in the fiddle/codepen/plunkr."). Woe betide the answerer whose company blocks code sharing sites. Don't get me wrong: I use jsfiddle a lot to try out ideas, but it's not that hard to copy and paste to a snippet. Let's not throw the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan that's also cumbersome and I had this myself several times, but in my opinion it's a different issue.

Comment: *I've also had many people argue with me when I ask them to include code in the question itself* @MikeMcCaughan - Especially when some other user(s) already told them to do a fiddle/codepen/plunkr instead in the comments.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Hiding (irrelevant) code is the *point*. When I read an answer, I want to see the code that actually answers the question asked, without having to wade through library inclusions and a bunch of styling that's purely to make the demo prettier. Users dumping dozens or hundreds of lines of code in questions where the problem could've been demonstrated in 5 or less remains a far more frequent problem than code being hosted off-site (and a more difficult one for editors to fix), and snippets encourage that bad behaviour.

Comment: This problem exists throughout all tags, and I suggest [a drastic amount of nuclear warning signs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295732) between the user and any text box.

Comment: Just some stream of consciousness ... I find Stack Snippets serving answers better than questions (Answerers usually know, how to use them correctly.) A first aid to the problematic usage in all _questions_ would be to allow Stack Snippets on questions tagged with "snippet-eligible" tags only. If implementing tag-dependent snippets is not possible (it's hard, I know, the free order of the question creation, later tag edits etc.), I'd consider to remove the tool from the question editor altogether. This maybe sounds harsh, but the ratio of 1:500 is not much over-estimated.

Comment: Personally, I contribute mostly under the jQuery tag and have always found snippets useful in both questions and answers and would hate to see them removed there. That said, I can see a change may be needed for other languages.

Comment: @MarkAmery Snippets can be hidden. When the code needs irrelevant noise to be runnable, the poster should hide the snippet, and copy the relevant parts outside. Otherwise, consider downvoting. The problem are not the snippets, the problem are that many people don't care to write good quality questions.

Comment: @Oriol hmm, this also seems to have been quietly made less shit since I last looked at snippets. I think originally expanding a 'hidden' fiddle wasn't possible at all (but I might recall wrongly), and then next there was no box around an 'expanded' snippet separating it from the rest of the post, so doing what you describe made the post confusing - you'd have visually indistinguishable consecutive blocks for non-snippet and expanded snippet code. That's no longer the case, although being able to open a fiddle in a separate tab *still* seems like a better interface despite the improvements.

Comment: @MarkAmery "*Open a fiddle in a separate tab still seems like a better interface*" ...until they remove your fiddle. JSFiddle did that to me.

Comment: @Oriol sure - the reliability of your demo staying around is the *one* way in which Stack Snippets are superior to JSFiddle. If only SO had just implemented a JSFiddle clone and left it at that!

Comment: I would be very sad to see snippets go. I use them and create snippets for askers where the question is improved with a formatted running version

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate being able to actually see someone's MCVE without leaving the question (yes, even when it's just a CSS question) but I realize I'm in the minority opinion on this, at least on Meta. That said, I've also seen people using them for the incorrect language.

> add another button that allows to remove snippets with one click when
> they are inappropriate.

I think I have a solution for this in the meantime. From what I can tell, there's a quick, manual way to flatten a Stack Snippet. You want to just edit out these lines in the Markdown:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- end snippet​ -->
```

The code just turns into a set of code samples at that point for the languages used.

Again, this is a solution in the meantime, not an argument against the feature request.

Comment: That's what I do. I open the edit view, use the browser search feature to search for `snippet` and then delete these lines. But that's very cumbersome and error-prone and it takes often several seconds when saving edits. I also removed them once on a answer where it actually was runnable code because I just always remove them when I see them, because in the tags I monitor they are just always invalid (except this one case :D )

Comment: *“I appreciate being able to actually see someone's MCVE without leaving the question”* – This assumes that the person creating the snippet actually knows what they are doing and sets it up properly. Which is unfortunately very rare.

Comment: @poke - I didn't think it was necessary to point out that I was referring to properly set up snippets but I can edit that in there if it will help.

Comment: I am making and converting snippets all day long. I enjoy helping Askers and Answerers alike. I do not make snippets containing angular, because I do not do angular, but for the rest I try.